# React ContextAPI: why is a local copy of store data getting updated?

Tags: reactjs, store, react-context

I'm using ContextAPI to manage a global state of data to be shared with any page wrapped in its Provider. In one case, i need to make a copy of what's in the store and alter it locally, but not affect the data for use in the other pages. However, my updates are directly updating the global store data.

In the code, `tmpStoreActivities.unshift(response); setCurrentActivity(tmpStoreActivities[0]);` is updating the Store's `activities` array, even though `activities` is reassigned twice to other vars, and I don't understand why. Am I misunderstanding the way the global store values get modified?

**STORE - Passes through ActivitiesProvider**

```
export const useActivitiesStore = () => {
  const activitiesService = new ActivitiesService();

  const [activitiesState, setActivitiesState] = useState(
    initialActivitiesState
  );

  const { activities } = activitiesState;

   //REDUCER       
   const setActivities = (newActivities) => {
    setActivitiesState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      ...{ activities: newActivities }
    }));

   const getRecentActivities = useCallback(async (params?: {}) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    resetActivities();

    try {
      //API call
      const recentActivities = await activitiesService.getRecentActivities(
        params
      );
      setActivities(recentActivities);

      //OPTIONAL USAGE: use this version of the data ONLY when a separate local copy is needed
      return recentActivities;
    } catch (error) {
      setError('Unable to Retrieve Activities');
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
    // disabling eslint because using this as dependency with dependencies causes infinite loop
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
  };

   return {
    activitiesState,
    getRecentActivities
  };
};
```

**COMPONENT**

```
import { useActivities } from '../../services/ActivitiesProvider';
    
export default function Activity() {
  const { activitiesService, activitiesStore } = useActivities();
  const { activitiesState, getRecentActivities } = activitiesStore;
  const { activities, searchResults, isSearching } = activitiesState;

  const [currentActivity, setCurrentActivity] = useState<IClassificationActivity>(null);
  const [currentActivities, setCurrentActivities] = useState<IClassificationActivity[]>(null);
    
//caching the initial load of activities, so infinite loops don't occur if we getRecentActivities later
  const storeActivities = useRef<IActivity[]>(isSearching ? searchResults : activities).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    //Get all the details for selected activity
    const getActivityDetails = async () => {
      const convertedType: number = type === ActivityType.Website ? 0 : 1;
      const convertedId = parseInt(id);
      try {
        const response = await activityService.getClassificationActivityDetails(
          convertedId,
          convertedType
        );
        if (response) {
          setActivityDetail(response);

          if (storeActivities?.length) {
            //if activities are pre-loaded from the Store, but the current activity does not exist in that array, add it to the front of the array and start the prev/next flow from there
            const currActivity = storeActivities.filter(
              (activity: IActivity) =>
                activity.type === type && activity.id === parseInt(id)
            )[0];
            if (!currActivity) {
              const tmpStoreActivities = storeActivities;
              tmpStoreActivities.unshift(response);
              setCurrentActivity(tmpStoreActivities[0]);
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        notificationService.error('Unable to load this Activity');
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    if (id && id !== 'undefined' && id !== 'null' && type) {
      getActivityDetails();
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [id, type, storeActivities, getRecentActivities]);

...
}
```

**ROOT**

```
<ActivitiesProvider>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path={Routes.Classification(':type', ':id')}
        component={Activity}
        exact
      />
    </Switch>
  </ActivitiesProvider>
```

Comment: When you assign your state to a new variable, all you are doing is creating a reference, not a copy. Then mutating it with ```unshift```.  You'll need to at least shallow, or potentially deep clone your array, or figure out a way to structure your state where it's not necessary to mutate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a variable, in Javascript when you reassign it to another you are actually not reassigning it, you are just pointing to it by reference.
For example when you have a state called `myState` containing an object like this:

```
{
    foo: "bar"
}
```

And you do something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState({ foo: "bar" });

  const myVar = myState;

  myVar.foo = "foo";

  console.log(myState); //Output: {foo: "foo"}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The output of the console log will tell you that the value of foo, is in fact "foo", despite the reassignment. But don't worry, there is a way to prevent this and it's called "spread".

You can make a copy of an object using the spread operator like this:

```
const myStateCopy = {...myState};
```

And now on, you are not referencing to `myState` anymore. You can check how spread works in this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-mcnulty-wyuyq). And please refer to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for more information

Edit:

You can do spreading with arrays too.

```
const myArrayState = [{foo: "bar"}];

const myArrayStateCopy = [...myArrayState];
```

Answer (score 0):

The Context API is used to share data between Components without the necessity of passing thought props. Doing so to avoid the issue with prop drilling.

What the Context API is doing is only sharing that information, in order to make your object immutable, you should check [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) or some third party libraries like [immutable](https://immutable-js.com/).

Comment: yes, thank you! For some reason I thought a "Store" had magical protection over its contents. But a mutable array is a mutable array is a mutable array.